# Android webview send image using postUrl

Tags: android, image, webview, base64

I'm working on an android app which uses webview and what I'm trying to accomplish is to successfully pass a base64 encoded image on my php file by using post.Url() and then display it on html5 canvas.

I have no difficulty in my php file (web) my problem is with this:

```
String url = "http://localhost/folder/postImage.php";

String encodedImage = iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";

String postData = "image=data:image/png;base64," + encodedImage;

webview.postUrl(url,EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
```

So, basically that's how my coding works, what I need is to retain the value of postData and not encode it to BASE64 again since it is already encoded in BASE64.

Instead of this :

```
webview.postUrl(url,EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
```

What should i put in here:

```
webview.postUrl(url,EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "???????"));
```

Hope you'll help me with my problem or at least suggest. THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP.UTF_8

I run it through http post  base 64 and php.

```
   try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String postURL = "http://www.mywebsite.com/foo.php";
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", image_str));

            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,
                    HTTP.UTF_8);
            post.setEntity(ent);
            HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();
            if (resEntity != null) {
                Log.i("RESPONSE", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```